# Проблемы использования модуля RIGHTS, ошибка 403 (YII1)

Tags: php, yii, права

После установки модуля **rights** (Christoffer Niska) , пытаюсь его использовать. Для этого делаю так:

```
class MyController extends RController
{
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            //'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'rights',
        );
    }

    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array(
                    'index',
                ),
                //'users'=>array('@'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    ........
```

и получаю:

> Ошибка 403 Вы не авторизованы для выполнения этого действия.

В чем причина такого поведения понять не могу. Печально то что информации по этой теме в интернете почти нет.

Comment: Зачем использовать то, для чего почти нет информации? 'users'=>array('?'), - попробуйте так

Comment: не помогло. а использовать приходится потому что это чужой проэкт

Answer (score 0):

В общем вот так корректно работает:

```
class MyController extends RController
........
public function filters() { return array( 'rights', ); } 
public function allowedActions() { return 'index'; }
........
```